# noImplicitAny "false" not seeming to work

Tags: typescript

When migrating a large application from .js to .ts, I am still getting a bunch of

`property does not exist on type ...` errors, despite having `"strict": false` and `"noImplicitAny": false` in my compiler options...

How can I turn off the type checking (for the time being during migration) so that compiling these files doesn't throw errors?

**UPDATE**

```
# md5_worker.ts

import { ChunkedFile } from 'chunked_file';

export class MD5Worker {
  constructor ({ data }) {
    this.chunkedFile = new ChunkedFile(data.chunkedFile.file, data.chunkedFile);
  }
...
}
```

Running `tsc` on this gives me: `property 'chunkedFile' does not exist on type MD5Worker`

Comment: Make sure noEmitOnError is off

Comment: @CertainPerformance but I want to emit the file... ?

Comment: Indeed - you want to emit it regardless of errors, so turn off noEmitOnError if it's on.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok-- well that flag is false by default, so that's not it.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: @Keith just updated with some code.

Comment: so strict mode and noImplicitAny aren't gona help you here. you'd pretty much need to turn off type checking for this to work. the property you're assigning to doesn't exist on the class you're working with. you need to add the property to the class to fix it. you can consider leaving unmigrated files as .js and just turn off type checking for js files pretty easily.

Comment: Yes, I assume classes are strict in TS.   The easy fix is just to put `chunkedFile` at the top of the class, you don't even need to define it's type.

Comment: @bryan60 how do you turn off type checking?  The point is I am trying to convert a project with a billion .js files, and I just need it to successfully compile  for now.

Comment: you can turn on allowJs and set checkJs to false, and leave unmigrated files as .js extensions. that's about it.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I converted from a large project, I just ended up using any everywhere.  But a quick look on NPM,  saw this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-to-ts-converter  maybe that might help..